# MongoDB $near query using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have some shops with products on them in my MongoDB db following this data model:
    Shop
    {
       idShop, name, location {lat, lon}, products [] of int
    }
If I run the following command in the mongoDB default console:

> db.shops.find({products:1, location:{$near:[41.391204,2.145381]}}).limit(300)

to find the shops that have product nº 1 ordered by distance I get the following results:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f410cefe4b03a0e3cff6f5a"), "name" : "Shop1", "location" : { "lat" : 41.389915, "lon" : 2.135628 }, "products" : [ 1, 5, 4 ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f410cefe4b03a0e3cff6f59"), "name" : "Shop2 Center", "location" : { "lat" : 41.388191, "lon" : 2.128816 }, "products" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f410cefe4b03a0e3cff6f5c"), "name" : "Shop3", "location" : { "lat" : 41.384712, "lon" : 2.172031 }, "products" : [ 6, 1 ] }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("4f410cefe4b03a0e3cff6f5d"), "name" : "Shop4", "location" : { "lat" : 41.384029, "lon" : 2.173936 }, "products" : [ 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }

Now, I want the same results but using my java servlet. If I search by only product number, the results are OK but not sorted. Then, if I try to sort them by adding a new key/value condition it doesn't return nothing. The code I'm using is the following:

> BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
>
> query.put("products", Integer.parseInt(idProduct));
>
> QueryBuilder query2 = new QueryBuilder();
>
> query2.near(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon));
>
> query.putAll(query2.get());
>
> curShops = collShops.find(query);

This returns an empty JSON. I've also tryed other ways like:

> BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
>
> query.put("products", Integer.parseInt(idProduct));
>
> ArrayList ar = new ArrayList(2);
>
> ar.add(Double.parseDouble(lat));
>
> ar.add(Double.parseDouble(lon));
>
> query.put("location", new BasicDBObject("$near", ar));
>
> curShops = collShops.find(query);

Without any luck.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have any experience with java driver, but it seem to me the problem is in this line

```
 query2.near(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon));
```

Accoridng to [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-NewSphericalModel) documentation,

> The code assumes that you are using decimal degrees in (longitude,
>   latitude) order. This is the same order used for the GeoJSON spec.
>   Using (latitude, longitude) will result in very incorrect results, but
>   is often the ordering used elsewhere, so it is good to double-check

Also from the [java mongodb-api-doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#near%28double,%20double%29), you can see

#### near

```
public QueryBuilder near(double x,
                         double y)
```

Equivalent of the $near operand

**Parameters:**

x - x coordinate

y - y coordinate

x-cordinate denotes Longitude here. So the location co-ordinates must be passed as `[lon,lat]` instead `[lat,lon]`

Change your query to

```
 query2.near(Double.parseDouble(lon), Double.parseDouble(lat));
```

to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty straight forward.  I have just posted an example that should walk you through the solution at http://chuckjohnson.wordpress.com/ - see http://chuckjohnson.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/geospatial-location-based-searches-in-mongodb-part-2-simple-searching/